# IIS Virtual Directory with MVC6 Angular Routing 1.4.5

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-routing

I have a MVC6/Angular site that will have multiple applications, but for now it just has one. When it is complete an example will be `App1` and `App2` being`.cshtml` pages with only a div with a `data-ng-app` and `data-ng-view` attribute:

**`mysite.come/virtualdir/App/App1:`**

```
<div class="row" data-ng-app="app-app1">
  <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**`mysite.come/virtualdir/App/App2`**

```
    <div class="row" data-ng-app="app-app2">
      <div data-ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

For angular, I understand if I have a virtual directory in IIS i need to include in my the header section of the _Layout.cshtml (Actually putting this in the _Layout will break development):

```
<base href="@Url.Content("~/")" />
```

My original templateUrl and angular links for app1 in development are:

```
  $routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "/views/app1/index.html"
  }); 

  $routeProvider.when("/items", {
    controller: "receiveController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    templateUrl: "/views/app1/receiveView.html"
  });

 // typical link in html page for app1
 <a data-ng-href="#/items"></a>
```

When I deploy to IIS i need to have the routing below to get to my index page to load when the the user navigates to `mysite.come/virtualdir/App/App1`

```
   $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "../views/app1/index.html"
      });
```

After that none of my other links work:

```
<a data-ng-href="#/items"></a> navigates me to mysite.com/virtualDir/#/items
```

How do I structure my hrefs in the html page? i tried playing around with the `../#/items/` and `..#/items` and adding the `..` to the other `templateUrl` but nothing seemed to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems like the simplest solution is to define the routes and hrefs as below. My problem was not having all three of these combinations at once. I thought angular defined the root of the angular routes based on my ~/App/App1 where I defined:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-app="app-app1">
  <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

so I needed in the app.js:

```
 $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/app1/index.html"
      })
```

@ the top of my _Layout.cshtml

```
<base href="/app/">
```

my href:

```
data-ng-href="App/App1#/items"
```